# Laravel - emails not sent using mandrill

Tags: laravel, email, mailchimp, swiftmailer, mandrill

I have mandrill configured for sending emails. Recently it stopped working so I tried to login to the mandrill account to find the following notice.[image] I checked the MailChimp account and it was linked but still nothing is working. I have followed the documentation for sending using [SwiftMailer](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582157-How-to-Send-with-SwiftMailer) but still nothing works.

In the documentation, it was stated to use `MANDRILL_USERNAME` and `MANDRILL_PASSWORD`. Are these the `SMTP` credentials is the account. If not, where can I find them in order to double check all configurations?

Comment: Did you set up the SPF and DKIM records?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using mandrill without problems but i have configured the service with a key to send emails.

This is how i do it:

Please check you have this in your .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mandrill
MANDRILL_SECRET=kOAYRloydIXXXXXXXXXXXxxx
```

Next check your config/services.php

```
 'mandrill' => [
        'secret' => env('MANDRILL_SECRET'),
    ],
```

And your config/mail.php

```
  'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The secret is the API key?!